# Is there a way to only refresh a view in Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot online shop application and my shopping cart component is accessible from several different views.

[image]

I make my views in Thymeleaf and those `-` and `+` are `<a th:href="@{'/products/addToCart/'+${product.id}}">`. Now inside my `products` controller I do some backend work and return a `redirect:home` but that kind of kills the whole point of putting these `-` and `+` there. I'd like it to return the same view from which the request was sent. Can that be done somehow? I don't like the idea of making seperate controllers for every view.

Comment: Do you want a full page refresh to happen when the user clicks the buttons, or do you want JavaScript to send an AJAX request?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Well the request would be handled by the controller anyway, so it would redirect back to /home, so same behaviour as now or am I getting something wrong? Basically what I want to achieve is when the user clicks + or -, I want the backend to handle the quantity change in cart and refresh the page. (return the same view as the one from which the request comes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `referer` (yes the official header has a typo) request header to know where you navigated from:

```
public String addProduct(@RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.REFERER, required = false) final String referrer) {
   // update cart

   // redirect to the referred
   return "redirect:" + referrer;
}
```

However, that is probably quite brittle. I'm not sure the referrer URL will always be there.

For something like this, I would probably use JavaScript to do an AJAX request to a dedicated endpoint that returns JSON. You can add `@ResponseBody` on a method in your controller so the response is not seen as a redirect or a page view, but a JSON string for example.

```
@ResponseBody
public CartInfo updateCart(...) {
  // do update to cart here

  // return a CartInfo object. It will be serialized with Jackson to a JSON string
}
```

In your HTML page, you will need to add some JavaScript to handle the AJAX call using plain JS or your framework of choice.

Comment: The solution with the referrer is exactly something I was looking for. It works for now, I'm planning to make this app as REST API with React.js frontend in the future but with the MVC I'll keep it the referrer way. Thank you!